# Winodws 7 Clock falling behind randomly by a few hours

Tags: windows-7, clock

A friend's laptop running Windows 7 keeps running behind by a few hours or days. It's an older laptop though I'm pretty sure that it is *not* the CMOS battery going bad as it would outright reset to minimally: *many years ago*. What could be causing the clock to fall back by just hours or days?

Answer (score 1):

More than likely it is the CMOS battery.  If it was completely dead, the CMOS settings would be lost, including the time.  However, being bad doesnt necessarily mean its dead.  An old or out of scpec CMOS battery can put out voltage below the specification to run the internal clock.  You can simply replace the battery, or test it with a multimeter.